# How are platform drivers managed in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Helo All,

I am trying to learn embedded linux.

Please provide clarity on below:

1. As DTB provides Board and SOC related information will it be sufficient to make sure correct drivers will be enabled?
2. How a correct driver will get selected and will it happen during build time or kernel runtime based on the DTB?
3. How are drivers for platform devices(UART, SPI, I2C etc) handled in Linux? I mean as different SOC's have different implementations(register and bit fields will be different) of these peripherals how a single driver will be able to handle both SOC's?
4. Is it sufficient to have well defined DTB about board and kernel to make Linux up and running on any platform.

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: As for your 3rd question, they don't use the same driver. Usually, the processor vendor provides those drivers, and the device tree 'compatible' property specifies the binding. If you check device trees for a beaglebone and a raspberrypi, you'll see they have different bindings for platform peripherals.

Comment: 1. Of course not, the crucial part is what your BootLoader / OS can handle. In ARM world it's still a problem to have multi-platform kernel (they need some like three or four to support most of the ARM platforms), while x86 has one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit.

Comment: 2. Both. If kernel have no driver, then obviously it has been deselected at compile time. Otherwise it will be dependent to many input parameters, including DTB (DTB is requirement which might be not satisfied).

Comment: 3. Big topic. Usually the way how to handle is called **platform quirks**. Depending on the platform and bus the device in question connected to it may be quite different type of quirks or their combinations. Read the actual driver code and you will get it after a while.

Comment: 4. Not yet, but Linux kernel developers are hardly working towards this. OTOH, hardware vendors (especially ARM-based ones) completely neglect upstream. So, it is an utopia.

Comment: Should I put all these comments as an answer?